# Generating function for $\frac{1}{(1-3x)^2}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I was tasked to solve the following recurrence using generating functions:
$$a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 3^n$$
Using $A(x) = \sum a_nx^n$ I arrived at the following decomposition (which I checked to be true):
$$A(x) = \frac{2-5x}{(1-3x)^2} = \frac{5}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{1-3x} + \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{(1-3x)^2}$$

I know that $\frac{1}{1-3x}$ corresponds to the generating function $\sum 3^nx^n$, but what about $\frac{1}{(1-3x)^2}$? It is never mentioned in any of the sources I am working with.

Comment: You can use that $\frac{1}{(1-3x)^2} = \frac{1}{3}(\frac{1}{1-3x})'$ and then differentiate term by term. Then adjust the index to get your generating function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n$, we can differentiate both sides we get

$$\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^{n-1}$$

**Edit:**

Explicitly, we can now substitute $3x$ for $x$ in the above to see

$$\frac{1}{(1-3x)^2} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n 3^{n-1} x^{n-1}$$

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't even aware I could just use differentiation here, thanks ^w^ I am just wondering how the factor $3$ can be used in there aswell

Comment: If you substitute $3x$ for $x$, then you get $\frac{1}{(1-3x)^2} = \sum n (3x)^{n-1} = \sum n 3^{n-1} x^{n-1}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Differentiate
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n = \frac{1}{1-x} 
\end{eqnarray*}
and now sub $x \rightarrow 3x$.